# What are Visual Studio file path limits?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, path, filenames

VS2010 has a mechanism that prevents you from creating projects if the resulting path is too long. I was going on the assumption that the maximum path length is 260 characters and the maximum directory path is 256 characters, but upon examination, VS2010 seems to set much shorter limits. Does anyone know why, and what those limits really are? Thanks.

Comment: You are possibly forgetting about the subdirectories that VS creates in the project directory.  Like bin\Release.

Comment: Ouch. Yes, indeed I forgot this.

Comment: However, even taking `bin\Release` into account, the numbers don't add up.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018131/visual-studio-and-maximum-length-of-the-path-of-a-project-reference