# Visual Studio and maximum length of the path of a project reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio

We have a number of projects, and each lives deep in a folder structure.  When one set of projects needs to reference a project in a different folder, the reference can fail because the relative path to is in VS is too long.

For example, project 1 will be in:

C:\folderA\folder1\folder2...\folderN\myProject1.csproj

It references another project:

C:\folderB\folder1\folder2...\folderN\myProject2.csproj

The HintPath to the reference is stored as a relative path, as in ............\folderB\folder1\folder2...\folderN\myProject2.csproj

When VS loads the solution, it can't resolve the reference because the absolute path it builds includes numerous ../'s such that the path exceeds 256 characters.  And the build fails.

We fix it by editing the csproj and putting in an absolute path, which is just silly.

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Why the down vote?  This is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - don't do that and it will not hurt. Consider less deep hierarchies and make related projects to live close.

MSBuild is managed application and CLR have restriction on path/file name length of about 256 characters...

Comment: Yes, reducing the depth of the folders will help.  I'll test this out.  We store all project artifacts in SVN, which means the actual software is down about 4 levels before we even have a *.sln file.  But overall this would require changes to many many projects.

Answer (score 3):

The max recommended project name length is 64 char. Team foundation server do not allow more than 64 char
See the following link
http://www.grabthecode.com/visual-studio/length-of-visual-studio-project-name

Answer (score 0):

You can find the naming conventions laid out by Microsoft in the below link [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/naming-restrictions?view=tfs-2018)

Comment: Provide context for links. Link-only answers are not good answers.