# cxx1: c1083 error cannot open source file"..\test\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cpp" in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I copied a project to some new location. But for `"..\"` the relative path is not changing. Then I tried to build the project with my visual studio 2015.

```
cxx1: c1083 error cannot open source file"..\test\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cpp"
```

First of all, in the same directory that contains `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cpp`, all other `cpp`s all have been successfully compiled except `'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cpp'`.    This is quite strange. 
I removed this `'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cpp'` from the project. Then readded, but still did not work.

However if I copied `'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cpp'` to e.g. `user\Documents`, and then added it again to the project. It worked.

Thus I guess this must have something to do with the length of my source code name and its path. (`'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cpp'` surely has a long name and the directory is very deep).

And secondly, if I use notepad++ to open `myproject.vcxproj`, the `'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cpp'` appeared quite far behind in the compiling sequence, e.g.`<ClCompile Include=`, in the original directory. If I copied it to `user\Documents`, it's location will be raised forward.

So any explanation for such a phenomenon? And any suggestions to make it work without copying `'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cpp'` to a different directory?

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018131/visual-studio-and-maximum-length-of-the-path-of-a-project-reference#8018295 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows

Comment: If it is really the length of the path to `xxx..xx.cpp` that matters, I'd like to know how long exactly that path is allowed to be.